# Facebook Aggregation Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, aggregation, facebook-timeline

I created a facebook timeline application with 4 actions and 2 Object types.
After that, i created an aggregation, to show my data in that timeline branded box (like Forsquare), that should display the sum of one action.

So for example i have scored 3 goals so far and one i score another one, it should display 4 goals (where the action is Score Goal and the object is Goal).

The problem is that the box is not appearing in my timeline although if i go to the activity tab, i can see that the action was made( Eg: User scored a goal).

Another issue i have is how can i display multiple aggregations (goals, shots) in the same timeline box (goal and shot are different objects)?

I'm using Facebook's JS Api.